# Connect to database for heavy traffic website Mysqli and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, mysqli

While I am coding I use the default connecting config which is:

```
//CONNECTION INFORMATION
DEFINE('DATABASE_USER', 'root');
DEFINE('DATABASE_PASSWORD', '*********');
DEFINE('DATABASE_HOST', 'localhost');
DEFINE('DATABASE_NAME', 'mydatabase');

// Override The Default Php.ini settings for sending mail
date_default_timezone_set("America/Indianapolis");


//CONNECTING
$con = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME);

if (!$con) {
     trigger_error('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
```

But this is for normal connection website, what if I have a really heavy traffic website as Facebook or other websites using MySQL database side, you have users, comments, changing data every second. Is all the same way or there is a better way to avoid the

> MAX_USE_CONNECTIONS

warning other than that the website is going slow but in first use is normal but later going slow day after day till restart the server.

I tried other solutions as using different database everyday, but I don't think this is a solution because I am looking to keep all data in one database for searching side.

---

For counting I am using query as:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `id` = '$user_id'");
```

For selecting and getting data I use:

```
$table = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE `id` = '$user_id'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($table) !== 0)
   {
      while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($table))
         {
               $id = $rows['id'];
               ......
         }
   }
```

---

**For live update** I have every second new change and I get the data using ajax.
Is every ajax call will open new connection? and do I have to close every connection after getting the data and why?

Comment: oh you expect Facebook like traffic - ok spend a few million a year on hosting to start with ...

Comment: @nogad I am asking to have a little bit idea about the heavy traffic websites how the connection is work, not to expect but if seeing something working great why do not think and look on it a little bit?

Comment: indexing is most important, that and avoiding, sorts, and the use of OR in your queries.  Mysql can handle hundreds of queries a second.  Max connections only apply when you are using the connection, so you would need that many connections at the same time, after the page is delivered you are no longer using the DB, and the connection can be reused.

Comment: Facebook and Twitter, use NoSQL, which is faster, but also much more limited in how the data can be searched.  This is why there is on search a post on facebook.  If you want to really increase search speed look into Sphinx Search.  you can do about 50k queries a minute with the right setup, but there are limits as you have to refresh the data it has when the data is changed.  So it's more complicated managing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is all the same way

Yes.

> Is every ajax call will open new connection?

Yes.

> do I have to close every connection after getting the data and why?

No. PHP will close it for you.

> I appreciate your time and your information to let me more knowledgeable to avoid as much as can the wrong way while coding :)

All your coding is wrong and for some years will be. Just learn and in time you'll be able ho create a site that can sustain a traffic that is 1/1000000th of Facebook.

However, it's impossible to put all the years of heavy learning into few paragraphs of a regular answer. Hope you understand.

Comment: I totally understand what you mean, the idea is there are some questions better to share it to get an idea to is "what I am thinking on is right?" such as the MAX_USER_CONNECTION the better way is to increase the value or mean there is a lot of calls to the database at the same time and should work on the coding side?

Comment: There is always work on the coding side but entirely different from what you think. It is not the way you put the code in your file - it's the way you put the code in your mind. Honestly, you just started with a sand castle but asking how to use your sandbox shovel to make a 5-storey building. Your questions are just irrelevant. Start from http://www.phptherightway.com/ if you want to get an idea what to ask

Comment: Just to make it straight: you can connect whatever way you want. It doesn't matter. The way you  connect is irrelevant to whatever your problems, real or imaginary ones. Just avoid persistent connections which someone would suggest to you, because people totally misunderstand their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to bench mark your code is to just time it...

```
$time = microtime(true);

//- code to time

echo number_format( (microtime(true) - $time), 4 );
```

That will give you the micro time in seconds to 4 decimal places for the code between them.  See where the code takes long time to run, and see what you can do to improve it, such as optimizing your queries etc.